# Can MySQLdb be Accessed From IDLE3 With Python Version 3.4?

Tags: python, mysql, linux

I am experimenting with IDLE3 to connect to a MySQl Database. The line 
`import MySQLdb` generates the error message:

> ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

I am using Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)

Python exists in two versions on my computer. One version: Python 2.7.6. The ability to import "*MySQLD*" works with this version of Python.

The other version is Python 3.4.0. The ability to import "*MySQLD*" does not work with this version.

While I knew there were two versions, I was unaware that entering the text "*python*" by itself gives you Python version 2.7.6. My intent, with IDLE3 was to work with Python version 3.4.0.  I realized my oversight based on the clues provided by holdenweb in his response below.

Based on further internet searching, a solution does exist for Ubuntu at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For users of Ubuntu, a solution does exist. Enter Synaptic Package Manager and locate the package "*python3-mysql.connector*" version 1.1.6-1. It is also available from the Ubuntu Software Center. This is a Python 3.4.0 connection to MySQL. It is unknown to me whether this is the newest version.

Additionally review: [Connecting to MySQL Using Connector/Python](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html)

There is also a newer Python connection for Python version Python 2.7.6. [Connector/Python 2.0.4](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/). I fiddled around with this connector, but apparently it is not compatible with Python 3.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that IDLE and Python aren't using exactly the same environment. The variable `sys.path` contains a list of the directories that the Python interpreter will search for libraries it has been asked to import. If you execute the following code in a plain Python interpreter and in IDLE you should see some differences:

```
import sys
print "\n".join(sys.path)
```

You can find out which directory the `MySQLdb` library lives in by importing it and then doing

```
print MySQLdb.__file__
```

If that directory doesn't appear in `sys.path` then you need to add it. The usual way of doing so is by setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable. You can find out how to set it for your particular environment in the Python documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Your print statement gave me: "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.pyc" which disclosed that I was unintentially using version 2.7. I had thought I was using version 3.4. Turns out that one has to enter python3 to actually use that version.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out

Comment: You may also find you have an `idle3` command if you still want to use idle.

Comment: "import mysql.connector" worked with idle3. Thanks again for contributing.